# Unity Scene view unable to pan

Tags: unity-game-engine, controls, unity-editor

In Unity Editor 2023.2.7f1, I am unable to pan my camera.
I am unable to pan my camera with the pan tool, or by right clicking with my mouse, or my middle clicking with my mouse.
This problem began right as around the time I installed the RoadArchitect plugin. https://github.com/MicroGSD/RoadArchitect
If anyone is able to help me, it would be much appreciated!

I have confirmed that all my mouse buttons are working. I have tried restarting the editor my computer. No luck, my pan tool remains useless and right clicking opens a context menu instead of rotating my view.
I am able to move my view using the arrow keys, but not with WASD and not with the pan tool or my mouse. I am not able to rotate my view at all.
When I create a new unity project in the same version, I am able to pan normally, even after installing the RoadArchitect plugin.

Comment: Did you try removing the asset, and then checking whether things are back to normal. Would be better if you can narrow done confidently on whether this asset itself is causing issue.